# Insert data via serialize() into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After looking through all the similar questions here, I still can't figure out how to get values from a multi-select into separate rows in a MySQL table. This is what I've got so far...

**PDO:**

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    return $stmt->execute($bindings);
}
```

**QUERY:**

```
if ( isset($_POST['add-show']) ) {
    $show_date = $_POST['show-date'];
    $promoter = $_POST['promoter'];
    $bands = $_POST['bands'];
    $bands_list = serialize($bands);

    query(
        "INSERT INTO shows(showdate, promoter_id, bands) VALUES(:showdate, :promoter_id, :bands_list)",
        array('show-date' => $show_date, 'promoter' => $promoter, 'bands_list' => $bands_list),
        $conn
        );
} else {
    $status = "Fill out the form";
}
```

The above function is used to insert values from text inputs on different forms, but I'm not sure it will also work for this form with the multi-select. Will I need a new function for that one? I'm thinking a foreach statement is required, but not sure what that would look like.

Do I need to provide additional information? I'm very new to PHP. Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you provide your html ?

Comment: 1. inserting serialized data into mysql is NO different from inserting any other data. 2. inserting serialized data in datamase makes no sense, spoiling whole idea of relational databases. Data should go in distinct table, not in single cell in a mess

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. How can I take an array from the multi-select and pull it apart so I can insert each ID into a separate row?